# update partial list inside a documents mongodb (v4)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of items in a document, each item have a field called for_sale which is boolean.

I have the `_id`, and a list of `item_id`'s and I want to update for this _id, all the `item_id`'s with the `for_sale = true`.

lets say the `item_id`'s I want to change are [1,3]

for example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598098245078027348"),
    "items" : [
            {
                    "item_id": 1
                    "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                    "price" : 10,
                    "for_sale": false

            },
            {
                    "item_id": 2
                    "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                    "price" : 20
                    "for_sale": false
            },
            {
                    "item_id": 3
                    "item_name" : "my_item_three",
                    "price" : 30
                    "for_sale": false
            }
    ]
}
```

the result I want:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598098245078027348"),
    "items" : [
            {
                    "item_id": 1
                    "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                    "price" : 10,
                    "for_sale": true

            },
            {
                    "item_id": 2
                    "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                    "price" : 20
                    "for_sale": false
            },
            {
                    "item_id": 3
                    "item_name" : "my_item_three",
                    "price" : 30
                    "for_sale": true
            }
    ]
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) update operation to achieve that.

The below update query is what you are looking for

```
db.test.updateOne({
    "_id": ObjectId("598098245078027348")
}, {
    "$set": {
        "items.$[elem].for_sale": true
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [
        {
            "elem.item_id": {"$in": [1, 3]}
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: ```errmsg=cannot use the part (expenses of expenses.$[elem].paired) to traverse the element```, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run it on Mongo Shell or are you using any particular programming language?

Comment: im using scala, with reactiveMongo which is the client library

Comment: You have to convert the above query to the scala's `reactiveMongo` equivalent as their syntaxes will be different. Let me know if you need help in achieving that in the best of my knowledge (although I dont know scala programming).

Comment: Your code should be something like this     `<MongoDB-Collection>.update.one(
    q = BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID),  // Change BSONObjectID to the OnjectID find criteria 
    u = BSONDocument(f"$$set" -> BSONDocument(
      f"items.$$[element].for_sale" -> true)),
    arrayFilters = Seq(
        BSONDocument("element.item_id" -> BSONDocument(f"$$in" -> Array(1, 3)))
    )
)
`    Change `BSONObjectID` to the find ObjectID filter for scala equivalent. Hope this helps

Comment: this is my code: ```def updateExpenses(metadata: Metadata, expensesIds: List[String]): Future[Report] = {
    collection.findAndUpdate(
      selector = Json.obj("metadata" -> metadata,
      update = Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("expenses.$[elem].paired" -> true)),
      fetchNewObject = true, upsert = false, sort = None, fields = None, bypassDocumentValidation = false, writeConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged, maxTime = None, collation = None,
      arrayFilters = Seq(Json.obj("elem.id" -> Json.obj( "$in" -> expensesIds))))
  }```

Comment: tried also to change it to update from findAndUpdate and there is no difference :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217426/discussion-between-hhharsha36-and-johnbigs).